# C++,Shared_ptr, Please tell me why my code is giving an error?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

getting error-

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\memory(1143,17): message : could be 'std::shared_ptr<int> &std::shared_ptr<int>::operator =(std::shared_ptr<int> &&) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\memory(1132,17): message : or       'std::shared_ptr<int> &std::shared_ptr<int>::operator =(const std::shared_ptr<int> &) noexcept'
1>E:\VS\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\main.cpp(14,10): message : while trying to match the argument list '(std::shared_ptr<int>, int *)'
1>Done building project "HelloWorld.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<string>
#include  <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<int> ptr = make_shared<int>();
    int l = 10;
    ptr = &l;
    cout << (*ptr) << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: The error messages you're getting say it all.  `std::shared_ptr<int>` does not have an `operator=()` that accepts an `int *` as an argument.   There is also no implicit conversion of an `int *` to a `std::shared_ptr<int>`  since the `shared_ptr` constructor which would do that conversion is marked `explicit`.  All of this combine to make the assignment `ptr = &l` invalid.

Comment: Replace `ptr = &l;` with `*ptr = l;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only allowed to assign another `std::shared_ptr<>` or `std::unique_ptr<>` to a variable of type `std::shared_ptr<>`, see the documentation of [`std::shared_ptr<>::operator=()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D) This prevents you from making mistakes where you assign a pointer to it that is not allocated on the heap, like you are trying to do in your code.

Note that your call to `std::make_shared<int>()` already allocates memory for an `int`, so why not use that?

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>();
*ptr = 10;
std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
```

You can even write this shorter and avoid some repetition:

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>(10);
std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
```

If you really want to assign another pointer to `ptr`, then you should ensure that pointer is shared or unique as well, like so:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
std::shared_ptr<int> l;
*l = 10;
ptr = l;
std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
```